# Is it possible to boot from the sd-card on the HDK8150 board?

Tags: android, ubuntu-core

I recently acquired the HDK8150 board. I am pretty interested in running a non-Android Linux OS there. After some hours of going through I found some interesting stuff:

1. I found that from Linux kernel 5.4, is supporting Snapdragon 855, so far so good!
2. There is one Ubuntu distribution named Ubuntu Core (https://ubuntu.com/download/qualcomm-dragonboard-410c). It seems it fully supports snapdragon but it is pretty bound to the DragonBoard-410C.
3. I found that there is an Ubuntu's parallel project named Linaro (https://www.linaro.org/) that looks pretty nice. My point is that I would like to check out any of them but I prefer not to flash the eMMC memory but run the system from the SD-card. I found it better since I am pretty sure I am gonna mess up with something, I am just starting with this... There is anybody that has experience on this topic with this specific board? There is any way to boot from the SD-card (it can be seen on the back that there are 8-switches labeled as "boot". There is no much documentation out there apart from the Quickstart guide)? Any suggestions on what OS to use?

Thanks so much and merry Christmas <3

PD: This question was originally posted here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232226/is-it-possible-to-boot-from-the-sd-card-on-the-hdk8150-board

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087932/boot-configuration-dip-switch-on-snapdragon-810 That was for an earlier board, but it looks like the way to find out is to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: Also: https://discuss.96boards.org/t/fastbootd-and-android-11-beta-with-dragonboard-845c/10131